# Dialog sends data to the onActivityResult() for the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a problem here , I got a dialog with some options , one of them is to start an activity with the intent to get the contacts list:

```
Intent i = new Intent
(Intent.ACTION_PICK , ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
i.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, Request_contacts);
```

the above code doesn't call the onActivityResult on the dialog or in the fragment , it calls the onActivityResult in the activity , even if I removed getactivity() it still call the activity one!

I'm assuming I can't put a bundle and pass it the fragment at run time , then how can I pass the information that was in the onActivityResult to the fragment of that activity ?

Comment: In your activity have you an instance of the fragment? in this case you can use a quick and dirty solution, and from the father activity method **onActivityResult** call a fragment's instance method. ( this create class coupling, if you must create a complex application probably this is not the best solution )

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I'm not sure what's going on , either it's a bug or I'm doing something wrong , but the other solution I came to is by calling fragment.onActivityResult in the activity onActivityResult().

Comment: Tried your code (of course without getActivity(), but just with Fragment.startActivityForResult() call) on KitKat and haven't observed any issue. Could you share more information?